# git copied local folder overwrite online repo

Tags: git, laravel, bitbucket

So I've copied a local git folder, and made a lot of changes in it. I would like to overwrite the online repo with this new one (so basically remove the link with the previous one, and copy this new one to the online repo and go from there on).

So far I tried:

```
git push -f origin master
```

and this did what I wanted (it seems). But now if I want to push, I first get the message:

```
 git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Then after doing that:
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:**************'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
    hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
    hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
    hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I understand it's because my other folder is interfering? But I'm afraid to pull the repo in, because it will overwrite my local folder?

So I tryd to remove the git in the original folder, but that's not helping.

So now my question: How can I overwrite the online repo with this new local repo and start from there on?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try to pull in the latest changes from origin master, merge with your own and push back.

Comment: Won't that overwrite my current local repo?

Comment: If your not sure, you can always backup.

Comment: Will do. I'll let you guys know what I did and how it went! Thank you for your information! :). 1 sec

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is called braching. That is: create a different version of it next to the original and merge it back in later. Pull gets the latest changes from a remote and tries toe merge them against your branch. After that everything is up2date and should be able to push back.

Comment: Perhaps a nice read: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: Well, not exactly. I actually just wanted to overwrite the online repo (but to be safe, I copied the local repo and then tried to push it, which led to this problem). But you are partly right! Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has answered the question, but that is not the correct way to do things in git. Hence, suggesting a generally followed approach

---

You can follow the below procedure

1) do `git pull`.

2) It may ask you to commit or stash the changes if there would be conflicts. If it doesn't then skip step 3

3) if it does, then do `git stash` followed by `git pull`.

4) If you had stashed(step 3) then you need to do `git stash pop` after `git pull` or else skip this step

5) After the above procedure, you may or may not get conflicts. If you do not get conflicts, then you are lucky enough. IF you do, then resolve the conflicts and then commit it

6) Now you can do `git push`

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up making a back-up.
Then I ran

```
git pull
```

After doing

```
git push --set-upstream master origin
```

I am able to do push and commit without any problems!

Comment: How did you make your back-up?

Comment: just zipped the folder I tryd to push, and then went my way with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add branch for just for your new code. 
So the code from master branch wont overwrite your code.

After you submit your branch you can see diff between branches.